# loading different menus per pages

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am trying to load wordpress menus specific to location pages. Someone knocked my question off of Wordpress.stackexchange because they said it's php specific.

```
<?php if(is_page(array('12038', '11763', '12042')) {
$locationMenu = 'Jackson';
} elseif(is_page(array('12220', '12223', '12226', '592')) {
$locationMenu = 'Hattiesburg';
} else {
$locationMenu = 'Top Menu';
}
?>
<?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => '$locationMenu',
            'theme_location'    => 'top',
            'depth'             => 3,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'navigation',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `$locationMenu` in inverted commas in the array you're passing to `wp_nav_menu()`, which means you're passing a string containing the text "$locationMenu".

Remove the inverted commas and the value of the variable will be passed instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes for the variable ($locationMenu) and try,

```
<?php if(is_page(array('12038', '11763', '12042')) {
$locationMenu = 'Jackson';
} elseif(is_page(array('12220', '12223', '12226', '592')) {
$locationMenu = 'Hattiesburg';
} else {
$locationMenu = 'Top Menu';
}
?>
<?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => $locationMenu,
            'theme_location'    => 'top',
            'depth'             => 3,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'navigation',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
?>
```